# On a non-linear PDE $p_t = e^{-p}p_{xx}$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider the PDE for $p:[0,T]\times [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ as follows:
$$
\begin{cases}
p_t = e^{-p}p_{xx}, & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times (0,1),\\
p(0,\cdot)\equiv -c &\text{for }x\in (0,1)\\
p(\cdot,0)\equiv 0 \equiv p(\cdot,1)&\text{for  }t\in (0,T),
\end{cases}
$$
where $c>0$ is some constant. Is there any wellposedness result on this initial-boundary problem? In particular, can we have the regularity of $p$ on $(0,T)\times (0,1)$?

Any answers, comments and references are highly appreciated.

PS: I did a search in Partial Differential Equations (Taylor), while nothing interesting has been found up to now.

Comment: I would imagine any reference on quasilinear parabolic equations, e.g., https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=1465184 , should contain some well-posedness theory for such equations as a special case.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you very kindly Professor Tao for pointing out this. Unfortunately I'm unable to open this link... Do you mind giving me a reference?

Comment: This is a book by Liebermann: https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/3302#t=aboutBook .  There is also an older book of Ladyshenskaya et al. at https://bookstore.ams.org/mmono-23 which is a classic reference.

Comment: @TerryTao Thanks again for the references. Do you know any references on the existence of the classical solution? This question is motivated by this post https://mathoverflow.net/questions/449442/lower-bound-of-the-solution-to-logarithmic-diffusion-equation

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a possibility would be to first get rid of the non-linearity by defining $\phi[\tilde{p}]$ to be the solution of :
$$
\begin{cases}
p_t = e^{-\tilde{p}}p_{xx}, & (t,x)\in (0,T)\times (0,1),\\
p(0,\cdot)\equiv -c &\text{for }x\in (0,1)\\
p(\cdot,0)\equiv 0 \equiv p(\cdot,1) &\text{for }t\in (0,T),
\end{cases}
$$
and then try to find a $p$ that satisfies $\phi[p]=p$ by some fixed-point arguments.

For one, if $p$ was a continuous solution of the original problem, then by the comparaison principle, $-c\leq p\leq 0$. So the space to study could be the space of continuous functions such that $p(\cdot,0)=p(\cdot,1)=0$ and $-c\leq p\leq 0$.

In that case, $e^{-\tilde{p}}$ would be very well bounded and behaved, so all the usual existence and regularity results apply (section 7.1 of "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans can pretty much be applied directly).
To me, the main difficulty from there is proving the continuity of $\phi$ or similar properties to apply fixed-point theorems. I don't know of many estimates that explicitly involve the diffusion coefficients.

Comment: Thanks Spintoo. This seems to be a very nice idea.